# Focus ArcMap application Window VBA

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, vba

How would you focus your ArcMAP application window using VBA?

I have a script that runs and selects polygons and zooms to them, but I would like ArcMap to focus and come to the front at that point.

Suggestions?

```
Dim pDoc As IDocument
Dim pApp As IApplication
Dim pAppROT As IAppROT

Set pAppROT = New AppROT

If pAppROT.Count > 0 Then
Dim p As Integer
Dim x As Integer
p = 0
x = 0
Do While p < pAppROT.Count
If TypeOf pAppROT.Item(p) Is IMxApplication And (pAppROT.Item(p).Document.Title Like "Report.mxd") Then

Set pDoc = pAppROT.Item(p).Document
Set pApp = pDoc.Parent
x = 1
pAppROT.Item(p).Visible = True

End Sub

Set focus = pAppROT.Item(p)

Exit Do
Else

End If

p = p + 1

Loop

End If

If x = 0 Then

    Set pDoc = New MxDocument
    Set pApp = pDoc.Parent

    pApp.OpenDocument ("c:\Report.mxd")

    pApp.Visible = True

End If'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the Win32 API SetForegroundWindow function as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Sub ViewArcMapWindow()
    SetForegroundWindow Application.hwnd
End Sub
```

However, if you run this directly from the VBA IDE, it may not work as desired since VBA may activate the IDE window when the script finishes.

Comment: How might i incorporate this into my code? I can't seem to figure out if i call the AppROT funciton or something different. thanks

Comment: Just cast your IMxApplication to IApplication and pass its window handle (.hwnd property) to the SetForegroundWindow function...

Comment: Inside what application do you run the VBA snippet?

Comment: I'm running it from a Access 2002 dbase to open arcmap and zoom to a specific polygon. The whole script works just fine, its bringing Arcmap to the front of the display thats catching me. I'll try your solution

Comment: I guess what I am confused mostly about is the syntax and how i might apply it to my code. I have dimensionalized IMxApplications as the IApplication but it still seems to hang/I am having troubles in solving the hwnd piece.